# mysql: unrecognized service

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I installed MySQL on Ubuntu 16.04 server by running:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

However when I run:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

I get the error:

```
mysql: unrecognized service
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Try `sudo service mysql start` first

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen the service shouldn't be *unrecognized*, even if it's inactive / disabled / masked though, surely?

Comment: @steeldriver This is 16.04. Doesn't the MySQL server need to be initialized before running?

Comment: @Jos it's been a while since I installed one, but I don't think so (unless the user takes steps to prevent `debconf` from asking the setup questions maybe?)

Comment: @steeldriver That is an idea. OP did you try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?